# Xdebug PhpStorm: Waiting for incoming connection with ide key

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I've searched a lot for this problem  when debugging php using PhpStorm with xdebug, I found 3 or 4 links discussing this problem, but none of them are useful.My Xdebug's version is 2.2.3, and PhpStorm'version is 6.03. I could debug every line step by step  except this one

```
$this->link = mysql_connect($this->dbserver, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
```

PhpStorm shows this error:Waiting for incoming connection with ide key "14841".
Here are my xdebug configuration:

```
 zend_extension="/usr/lib/xdebug.so"
 xdebug.remote_autostart=1
 xdebug.show_local_vars=1
 xdebug.dump.GET=*
 xdebug.dump.POST=*
 xdebug.dump.SERVER=*
 xdebug.auto_trace=On
; default trace output directory /tmp
 xdebug.collect_vars = On
 xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp
 xdebug.collect_params=4
 xdebug.collect_return=On

 xdebug.profiler_enable=Off
; default trace output directory /tmp
 ;xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
 ;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=On
;test.php?XDEBUG_PROFILE
 xdebug.remote_enable=On
 xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
 xdebug.remote_port=9001
 xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
 xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp"
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
 xdebug.idekey=PHPStorm
```

I add  these lines " xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 
xdebug.idekey=PHPStorm ", also resisted ide ,it is still the same
 i assure that the three parameters are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote:

> PhpStorm shows this error:Waiting for incoming connection with ide key "14841".

But you use:

```
 xdebug.idekey=PHPStorm
```

Those ide keys need to match. PHP Storm is a bit funny about it.

But then you also said:

> I could debug every line step by step except this one
>
> ```
> $this->link = mysql_connect($this->dbserver, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
> ```

How are they different? Is there different behaviour, or just doesn't it stop?

Comment: Thanks,i found the cause later,i noticed that i forgot to install mysql.so extension.so this function failed.

Comment: Thats nothing to do with above. Please check my post below

Answer (score 7):

For me, the debugger never connected and I saw the *Waiting for incoming connection with ide key* message because I set set my Server configuration to port 9000. **This should be set to port 80** (or whatever other port the webserver is listening to! This was confusing to me because it's right next to the Debugger dropdown and I figured it was to set the Xdebug port.

[image: You do NOT want to set this value to the debug port]

The Debug port is configured in Settings->Languagues & Frameworks->PHP->Debug. Set this to 9000 or whatever you configured php.ini to be.

[image: Set Debug port to 9000 in PHP Debug settings]

Just a note, I was using IntelliJ IDEA, but it's all the jetbrains platform.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. In my case it was caused by misunderstanding PHPStorm/IntelliJ PHP debugging modes. There are two modes:

1. "Local" PHP debugging
2. "Remote" PHP debugging

**When you use the "local" debugging, IDE key is autogenerated**

This means, that primitive bookmarklets, created at http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/ *will not work* in local mode: the bookmarklet contains a hardcoded IDE key, but PHPStorm will generate a random one!

The solution is to enable "Remote" PHP debugging mode (it is currently called "PHP Remote Debug") in "Run/Debug Configurations" and set the IDE key in the right pane of the create launch configuration.

"DBGp proxy" in global settings is probably not what you want; create a "Remote" debug config and set the IDE key there.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue in a local installation.
I fixed it by unselecting the setting: Use Path Mappings

Found under the Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Servers

Comment: Why do you think that solved it? Did you use no symlinks?