# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I bought and installed PhpStorm. Next I decided configure xdebug. I set up and saw this info

> "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'"

I so much did and nothing didn't help me. Please help me.

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
;xdebug.collect_params = 4
;xdebug.collect_return = 1
;xdebug.collect_assignments = 1
;xdebug.collect_vars = 1
xdebug.dump.REQUEST = *
xdebug.dump.SESSION = *
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.COOKIE =
;xdebug.dump.FILES =
;xdebug.dump.GET =
;xdebug.dump.POST =
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.dump_once = 1
xdebug.dump_undefined = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format = ""
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
;xdebug.manual_url = "http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
;xdebug.remote_log = "none"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.scream = 1
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
;xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
;xdebug.trace_format = 1
;xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
;xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%H%R"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
```

Comment: Official manuals (with pics and stuff): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable '`Can accept external connections`' in `Preferences -> Build, Execution, etc. -> Debugger ?`
Also try adding the remote log path

```
xdebug.remote_log = E:/Server/tmp/xdebug.log
```

so that you can collect xdebug logs and see what it has to say about it.
See this [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715128/xdebug-phpstorm-waiting-for-incoming-connection-with-ide-key) for additional help

Comment: Yes "Can accept external connections" enable, I added xdebug.remote_log = "%sprogdir%/userdata/logs/xdebug.log" and nothing there

Comment: @FAST Well ... if xdebug log file is empty then it's either 1) xdebug cannot write here (permission issue?) or 2) xdebug does not see actual debug request or not configured correctly. Please show your `phpinfo()` output captured via browser

Answer (score 1):

You can try chrome [XDEBUG extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) with simple xdebug configs. It works fine for me.

here are my configs

```
zend_extension = E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 4096
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time=10800
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.scream = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem yesterday. I rummaged all the answers to this question on the Internet Unluckily, nothing works for me. However, I accidentally found a solution this morning.

1. OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.4
2. Xdebug: v2.9.6
3. Phpstorm: 2019.3.4 (don't reinstall your Phpstorm, this won't work.)

## Step 1:

```
    [Xdebug]
    zend_extension = "/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.13/pecl/20180731/xdebug.so"
    xdebug.remote_enable = on
    xdebug.remote_host = localhost
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
    xdebug.idekey= PHPSTORM
    xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

## Step 2:

Phpstorm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug -> Debug port : 9000

## Step 3:

Phpstorm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers -> [delete all of configurations] Like below：

[image]

## Step 4:

start listening for PHP debug connections. like below:

[image]

## Step 5:

Start your PHP project by "php artisan serve" on your terminal.
Don't forget to add a breakpoint or turn on "Break at the first line in PHP script"

It works...wow!!!

[image]

If you don't want to enable debug mode, just turn off "listening for PHP debug connections"

Hope you have solved this problem now.