# PHP Remote Debug stuck at "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'"

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm, Docker and Xdebug. However, when I mark a breakpoint in the PHP code. The Xdebug shows nothing with the error

> Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'

And when I try to install composer by `docker-compose exec app composer install`. The error "Xdebug could not open the remote debug file '/tmp/xdebug.log'." occurs.

Could you please tell me how to enable the Xdebug?

Comment: 1) *"And when I try to install composer ... The error "Xdebug ..."* This suggests that you have configured Xdebug to try and debug every single request/execution of .php file (by having `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`). The *"Xdebug could not open the remote debug file '/tmp/xdebug.log'."* part means that Xdebug cannot write into his log file -- double check your path and permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xdebug PhpStorm: Waiting for incoming connection with ide key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715128/xdebug-phpstorm-waiting-for-incoming-connection-with-ide-key)

Comment: 2) *"The Xdebug shows nothing with the error "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'""* This is shown by IDE and not Xdebug. This means that IDE has not yet received an Xdebug connection and is waiting for Xdebug to connect and initiate debug session. Such error usually means that Xdebug is not configured correctly (e.g. wrong IP address is used), you you have misconfigured your Docker, or Xdebug port is busy or your local firewall... https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/08/quickstart-with-docker-in-phpstorm/